# Spring POST relationship json not working

Tags: json, spring, jpa, relationship, many-to-one

I was trying to post an object with relationship to server.
But I got an error.

My entity:

```
@Entity
public class District implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Column(unique = true)
private String name;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JsonBackReference
@JsonUnwrapped
private City city;

@JsonManagedReference
@JsonIgnoreProperties
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "district", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<Region> regions = new HashSet<>();

@JsonIgnoreProperties
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "district", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<Drugstore> drugstores = new HashSet<>();

//getter and setters
```

Here is my controller:

```
@PostMapping("/admin/district")
ResponseEntity<?> create(@RequestBody District request) {
    service.create(request);
    return null;
}
```

Here is my error:

[image]

If I send null json, I get this error again.
Can anybody help?

Comment: how is the controller looking?

Comment: @dimitrisli i add now

Comment: @dimitrisli yes i add RestController annotation above of controller class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after i try several minutes i found the solution.

> If use @JsonBackReference in project more than twice, should
>   distinguish them with a specific Reference name.

so i do like this:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JsonBackReference("district-city")
private City city;

@JsonManagedReference("district-region")
@JsonIgnoreProperties
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "district", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<Region> regions = new HashSet<>();

@JsonIgnoreProperties
@JsonManagedReference("district-drugstore")
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "district", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<Drugstore> drugstores = new HashSet<>();
```

and the solution solved.

hope to help someone ...